# Append on table if data not exist jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that appends a row data. What I want is remind the user if they will add details that already exist in the table.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7H4T4/5/)

```
$('#try').click(function() {   
var text = document.getElementById('add');
    if($('#test td:contains("'+text.value+'")') == true) {
        alert('not allowed');
    }else{   
        $('#test').append('<tr><td>' + text.value + '</td></tr>');
    }
text.value = '';    
});
```

What's happening in my code is, it doesn't filter on line **:contains**.

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#try').click(function () {
    var test = $("#add").val();
    var sample = $("#add2").val();
    var flag = 0;
    $("#test").find("tr").each(function () { //iterate through rows
        var td1 = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(); //get value of first td in row
        var td2 = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text(); //get value of second td in row
        if ((test == td1) && (sample == td2)) { //compare if test = td1 AND sample = td2
            flag = 1; //raise flag if yes
        }
    });
    if (flag == 1) {
        alert('not allowed');
    } else {
        $('#test').append('<tr><td>' + test + '</td><td>' + sample + '</td></tr>');
    }
    $("#add").val("");
    $("#add2").val("");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7H4T4/8/)

Comment: can I do a side question for this post?

Comment: What if I want two(2) parameters to be depend? Example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7H4T4/7/). What I want here is to append the inputs with different details. Ex. **Test 1 and Sample 2** will append but **Test 1 and Sample 1** will not be appended.

Comment: You're so amazing. This is exactly what I really want to happen.

Comment: I'm still thinking how your code works. Can you explain me how. I'm so amazed that's why I want to know.

Comment: @myRM I have added comments in my answer. hope it is clear to you now.  is it clear or still you have doubts?

Comment: No, it's just that I was amazed, because I can't even think of that.

Answer (score 4):

To start with, you must test the length of a jQuery object to know if there's an element in the DOM :

```
if ($('#test td:contains("'+text.value+'")').length) {
```

But your code will fail if `text.value` contains anything that breaks the selector, for example quotes, so you'd better directly test the content with `filter` :

```
var elems = $('#test td').filter(function(){
     return this.innerHTML.indexOf(text.value) !== -1
});
if (elems.length) {
```

[Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXc2n/)

It's possible that what you want isn't in fact, to test if the cell "contains" the string, but if it contains only that string (i.e., you want to allow `"test 21"` and `"test"` when there's already `"test 2"`). To do that, you may filter this way :

```
var elems = $('#test td').filter(function(){
     return $(this).text()===text.value
});
if (elems.length) {
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WKuQ/)

Comment: Can you fix the fiddle link I gave, so I can see?

Comment: and yes as a note... **contains checks for particular text/character**... so since `test 1` already exist... even just `test` is not allowed, or `t` or `te` or `1` so on.. so think before u use `contains` :)..

Comment: @bipen I see that's why **:contains** is not advisable in this kind of situation.

Comment: @dystroy exactly what I need. Thank you so much. One more thing, what actually happens during `elems.length`?

Comment: `elems.length` is the number of matching elements. As it's a number, the only way for it to be falsy (i.e. pass as `false` in an `if`) is to be `0`.